# CSS Как сделать такую кнопку?

Tags: html, css, button

[image]

Т.е добавить засечки, и появляется эффект, что она держится за верхний блок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению слишком маленькое описание.
Сделал то что вы хотели. Как это делается: берём кнопку (оранжевая) и по верх её накладываем псевдоелемнт before c закруглёнными углами что создаёт эффект (засечек).
Посмотреть код, можете по ссылке :`

```
<div class="btn-wrap">
  <div class="btn">
    Выбрать
  </div>
</div>

.btn-wrap{
  z-index: 1;
  background: #a1a1a1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
    padding-top: 150px;
}
.btn{
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 65px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  
}
.btn::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: -120px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
`
```

https://codepen.io/hel1_yeah/pen/YzqpmRO

Answer (score -3):

Простое пояснение добавь сверху блок с margin bottom -2,3 px и border radius